# Apéry's constant $\zeta(3)$ fastest convergent series

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, algorithms

**UPDATE Feb.02.2024**

The series below, Eq.(3) for computing and Eq.(2) for verifying, were applied by Andrew Sun on Dec.22.2023 to get over $2\cdot10^{12}$ decimal digits and break the number of currently known decimals of Apery's Constant. The whole process took about 12 days as it is reported in [[1]](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/#Records), [[2]](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/records/2023_12_16_zeta3.txt) and [[3]](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/records/2023_12_22_zeta3.txt).

It is worth to point out that these proven fast ζ(3)
formulae Eqs.(1,2 & 3) are un-published and they have been only placed here in MO.

---

By means of a generalized search of hypergeometric-type series based on Dougall's sum and applying the Wilf-Zeilberger method as implemented by [Jesús Guillera](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04385.pdf) to prove some classical constants relationships, three proven series are found for Apéry's constant $\zeta(3)$. These series show the lowest known computing costs to apply the binary splitting method using A. Yee's [y-cruncher](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/) software, a high performance platform to compute a huge number of digits of some classical constants, having set several records in this regard. These series are currently the fastest known to calculate an arbitrary number of digits for this constant.

I am not sure if any of these series has been published, so the question is simple.

Are these series known?

The first one is $$\begin{equation*}\zeta(3) = \frac{1}{12}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{P(n)}{n^5(2n-1)(3n-1)(3n-2)(4n-1)(4n-3)\binom{3n}{n}^2\binom{6n}{3n}^2\binom{7n}{3n}}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}$$ with $$P(n) = 376698240\,n^7 - 935880048\,n^6 + 938536090\,n^5 - 491213175\,n^4 + 144859115\,n^3 - 24133842\,n^2 + 2114280\,n - 75600$$ It has convergence rate $\rho = 1/22235661$ giving about $7.35$ decimal digits per term. The computing cost $C_s$ is measured through $$C_s = - \frac{4\,d}{\log\rho}$$ where $d$ is the denominator's polynomial degree. In this case $d = 10$. This gives $C_s=2.3645...$.

The second series has $C_s = 2.3070...$ with $d=14$ and $\rho=1/34828517376$ giving about $10.54$ decimal digits per term. It is $$\begin{equation*}\zeta(3) = \frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{P(n)}{R(n)\cdot\binom{3n}{n}\binom{6n}{3n}\binom{8n}{4n}\binom{9n}{3n}\binom{10n}{5n}}\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}$$ where $$P(n)= 250765325100000\,n^{11} - 1087318449630000\,n^{10} + 2067749814046250\,n^9 - 2269551612681475\,n^8 + 1592180015776565\,n^7 - 746938801646725\,n^6 + 238210943593421\,n^5 - 51452348050672\,n^4 + 7352050259484\,n^3 - 660416507568\,n^2 + 33552610560\,n - 731566080$$ and $$R(n)=n^5\,(2n-1)\,(3n-1)\,(3n-2)\,(4n-1)\,(4n-3)\,(5n-1)\,(5n-2)\,(5n-3)\,(5n-4)$$

The 3rd series has $C_s=2.0514...$ with $d=14$ and $\rho=-1/717445350000$ giving about $11.86$ decimal digits per term. It can be expressed as $$\begin{equation*}\zeta(3) = \frac{1}{48}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)}\,P(n)}{R(n)\cdot\binom{5n}{n}\binom{5n}{2n}\binom{9n}{4n}\binom{10n}{5n}\binom{12n}{6n}}\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}$$ where $$P(n)= 1565994397644288\,n^{11} - 6719460725627136\,n^{10} + 12632254526031264\,n^9 - 13684352515879536\,n^8 + 9451223531851808\,n^7 - 4348596587040104\,n^6 + 1352700034136826\,n^5 - 282805786014979\,n^4 + 38721705264979\,n^3 - 3292502315430\,n^2 + 156286859400\,n - 3143448000$$ and $$R(n)=n^5\,(2n-1)^3\,(3n-1)\,(3n-2)\,(4n-1)\,(4n-3)\,(6n-1)\,(6n-5)$$

A non-native implementation of such algorithms has been done for y-cruncher software preparing custom input files for each formula. I tested these series under this special platform against some classical formulas that has been used to break the $\zeta(3)$ digits number record. In particular the [Amdeberhan-Zeilberger](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v4i2r3/pdf) series **AZ** (1997) $C_s=2.8854...$ and [Wedeniwski's](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/Zeta3.txt) series **Wed** (1998) $C_s=2.7554...$.

Testings were done on an Intel Core Kaby Lake i5-7300U 3.5 Ghz 32 Gb RAM standard laptop with Windows 11 Pro 64bit OS. The following Table shows timings in seconds to get 50.000.000 decimal digits of Apéry constant.  $Arch$ refers to the word size of the formula's input integer polynomial coefficients. $N$ indicates if the series summand has $N$ terms grouped from the basic formula. Timings are the average of 5 runs.

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline {Series} & {Time\,s} & {Arch.} & N & \frac{dec.\ digits}{term} & C_s & d \\
\hline \mathrm{Eq.(3)} & 23.361 & 64-bit & 1 & 11.86 & 2.0514 & 14\\
\hline \mathrm{Eq.(2)} & 26.387 & 64-bit & 1 & 10.54 & 2.3070 & 14\\
\hline \mathrm{Eq.(1)} & 27.465 & 32-bit & 1  & 7.35 & 2.3645 & 10 \\
\hline \mathrm{Wed-II} & 33.095 & 64-bit & 2 & 10.08 & 2.7554 & 16\\
\hline \mathrm{AZ-III} & 34.697 & 64-bit & 3 & 9.03 & 2.8854 & 15\\
\hline \mathrm{Wed-I} & 34.893 & 32-bit & 1 & 5.04 & 2.7554 & 8\\
\hline \mathrm{AZ-I} & 37.603 & 32-bit & 1 & 3.01 & 2.8854 & 5\\
\hline \end{array}
\end{align*}

Considering this limited scope of testings, it is observed that, under the y-cruncher's generic algorithm custom implementation,  these -I guess- new series provide a significative increment of computing speed for Apéry's $\zeta(3)$. Eqs.$(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ are about 21%, 24% and 33% faster than classical Wedeniwski's formula respectively.

Finally, the proof of these series is obtained by means of WZ certificates (too long to put them here) through the code in [Guillera](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04385.pdf) with input patterns $$entry = 2+7\,n,1+3\,n,1+2\,n,1+1\,n,1+1\,n$$ $$entry = 2+10\,n,1+4\,n,1+3\,n,1+2\,n,1+1\,n$$  $$entry = 2+11\,n,1+4\,n,1+3\,n,1+2\,n,1+1\,n$$ for Eqs.$(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ respectively.

Comment: Interesting idea that of adding the computation of the cost of binary splitting to my program

Comment: What do your results imply about the irrationality measure of $\zeta(3)$?

Comment: Muchas gracias a Ud. doctor Guillera, for providing the references without which it would have been impossible to discover these formulas. In particular, for making public the code to find and prove new series, which I could
modify to automatically calculate the binary splitting computational costs $C_s$

Comment: Timothy Chow, this is a very difficult question. I have not (I guess nobody currently has) an answer. As it can be seen, WZ resulting formulas have a (very) high weight which makes them very difficult to theoretically work with.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, a google search of part of the formula shows no other results but this one, suggesting it is original

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22376698240%22

It' possible  to make arbitrary series by just  coming up with bigger and bigger polynomials p(n) and r(n). Such polynomials arise  by starting with a kernel, which is the original integral that yields the desired constant, and then using polynomial division  on the integral to make new binomial identities. It's  possible to make an arbitrary number of these, but the most impressive series are those that have a fast convergence and small polynomials . For Zeta(3), you would use three integrals for the underlying 4F3 hypergeometric function.  This is done with Catalan's Constant on page 13 here, which requires two integrals.  https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3919892

The more interesting question is how to derive these. Just saying "WZ algorithm" is not that helpful. There needs to be a mathematically precise way to finding the fastest  series constrained by a certain hypergeometric form.  For example, the fastest non-reciprocal pi formula (if we limit to reciprocal of pi, Ramanujan-type formulas would obviously win) that can be expressed as the composition of two 3f2 series in which all the parameters are rational.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The key is "those that have a fast convergence and small polynomials". This means to minimize the computing cost $C_s=\frac{-4d}{\log\rho}$. I have not worked with integrals. Just looking for Wilf-Zeilberger pairs from Dougall's well poised series where you have 5 parameters to work with, it is possible to find such fast formulae. Most of them come from a selected set of parameters. I think I have exhausted the searching of these series for $\zeta(3)$ with polynomials having 32-bit word size coefficients.

Comment: Some of the general principles behind these kinds of investigations are described by Zeilberger and Zudilin in their paper, [The Irrationality Measure of Pi is at most 7.103205334137...](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06345). However, I'm not sure that they give a "mathematically precise way to find the fastest series constrained by a certain hypergeometric form"; it is still something of an art form.

Comment: Timothy, note that "fast" in my note must not be understood in the classical sense of "how many digits by term you get" for a given series, in other words it is not (only) related to the convergence rate $\rho$. The measurement of how fast a series is, is related to a concept of algorithmic exertion economy, which traduces in computing time. For computing certain hypergeometric forms with binary splitting algorithms we need first low degree polynomials and second a good convergence rate. The combination of both elements yields a fast series.